# Windows 8 tablet streaming support

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, smooth-streaming

Does anyone know which video streaming delivery methods will be supported natively and within metro style apps on Windows 8 tablets (and also Windows Phone 8)?

I am hoping one of the following will be supported natively:

Apple HLS (Http Live Streaming)
Microsoft Smooth Streaming
RTSP streaming

I know Smooth streaming is supported in metro style apps, but I can't find any way of presenting links on my site which (if clicked) hand off video play back to the native video player.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default player (like Windows Phone) on Windows 8, you will have to use some libraries.
Try this one:
http://playerframework.codeplex.com/